# "not running as user lfs, you should be" error

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi3, linux-from-scratch

### Description

Trying to install `pilfs` (the `LFS` for raspberry) on my raspberry pi 3. I'm following the guide as posted here: http://www.intestinate.com/pilfs/guide.html

I'm currently following their "chapter 8"

> 8 Building Chapter 5 [5.4. Binutils - Pass 1]
>
> Alright, this is the moment of truth. Will you make your way through
>   chapter 5 slow and steady, or just execute the build script and go do
>   something else for 30 hours? This is for you to decide ... I've done
>   both :)
>
> Also, here is where you might want to start a tmux or screen session.
>   Because if you break your ssh connection or your router has a hickup,
>   your build will just stop.
>
> So you've made up your mind? Okey, script runners, start your engines:
>
> `cd $LFS/sources`
>
> `chmod +x`
>
> `ch5-build.sh`
>
> `./ch5-build.sh`
>
> The script will report your SBU time after the first binutils build has finished, mine
>   is usually around 1 hour.
>
> For those brave souls who are working through the chapter by hand,
>   check out the about page and read the build scripts to figure out
>   what's going on.

### Error

When I do `./ch5-build.sh`, it's causing the following mesage:

> Not running as user lfs, you should be!

### Question:

What step did I miss for this to happen? How do I run myself as a "lfs user"?

Answer (score 0):

You need to enter `su - lfs`  in the command line and then enter your password. This is assuming you have created the lfs user earlier  in the book. From there, you can run the shell script.